# How to calculate public holidays payable hours

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to write an excel formula that categorises the information on each date row as being a public holiday (PH), weekend (WE) or weekday (WD). Public holidays should display as PH regardless of the day they fall on. Days should only be categorised as WE or WD if they are not public holidays.

Here is the sample dataset.

[image]

I also need to write a formula to insert hours into column F(PH Payable hours) if 1) It is a Public holiday AND (2) the employee has worked at least 3 out of the last 4 like days.  The number of hours inserted must be the average of the prior like days.

For an example : If the Public holiday falls on a Monday refer to hours worked on the previous 3 or 4 Mondays.

This is one of my look up table to find out PH

[image]

I have written this formula but unable to populate PH in "Date category" column

=IF(COUNTIF(H52:I57, B54) > 0, "PH", IF(WEEKDAY(B54, 2) > 5, "WE", "WD"))

Any help would be apprecaited.

Comment: Per [this meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90920/827123), Excel questions should really be posted on Superuser, not here, because they're not really about programming.

Comment: So use the function Excel provides NETWORKDAYS.INTL() as it allows you to specify holidays, and which days are weekends etc etc

Comment: @ZacAnger So the "Solver" tag here has more than 1600 questions while "Solver" over on SuperUser has 23... Guess why I am here.

Comment: @SolarMike interesting! I think StackExchange as a whole has a big problem with not advertising enough that it's a whole network of sites and that StackOverflow really is meant to just be for programming. In light of those tag counts, I'll retract my close vote.

Comment: @Zac I have always found Excel questions tend to be more interesting over here :)

Comment: @SolarMike, i do not have start and end date. You need to have start date and end date to use NETWORKDAYS.INTL() function.  not sure how to execute this function to populate PH

Comment: Looks like your start date is 16.3.2022 and end date is 18.3.2022

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Your formula is OK, just need to put anchors in so you can copy it down:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(H$2:I$7, A2) > 0, "PH", IF(WEEKDAY(A2, 2) > 5, "WE", "WD"))
```

(2) If you have Excel 365, you can filter the data to include only days which fall on the same weekday, are earlier than the current day and are themselves working days then average the last four ( or three if only 3/4 have been worked):

```
=IFERROR(
LET(range,A$2:E$14,
Date,A$2:A$14,
class,E$2:E$14,
prevDays,FILTER(range,(WEEKDAY(Date)=WEEKDAY(A2))*(Date<A2)*(class="WD")),
last4,CHOOSECOLS(TAKE(SORT(prevDays,1,-1),4),3),
worked,SUM(--(last4>0)),
IF(worked>=3,AVERAGE(last4),"")),
"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tom. Fixed problem 1 by putting anchors. Problem 2: I was trying to populate payable hours for PH days. I have office 365. I have applied your logic but PH payable hours populating for the date 15th April 2022 only. Dont know why not for others. could you pls suggest?

Comment: It's difficult to know if your data is the same as mine. It only checks 'like' days so it would suggest that the only working days which qualify happen to be Fridays?

Comment: Its the same data structure mentioned in your solution thread. In your case PH hours appearing for 18th and  25th April. Its not showing up on my end.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to your question plz, showing the payable hours formula for (say) 18/4/22 ?